# No items in shopping cart, but actually there is

Tags: magento2, cart, login, logout

After I added an item in the shopping cart, and I logged-out.

When I log-in again, there's no item in the shopping cart.

However, once I add another item in the cart, the previous one is shown again.(Finally there will be 2 items in the cart)

Expected behavior should be showing 1 item in the cart after re-login.

Comment: its a magento 2 bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377 , turning on cache did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on this problem and after some RND i was found this links:

["No items" in minicart in 2.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377)

[Magento2: Minicart not showing items](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7550)

[mini cart does not clear after placing an order - magento 2.0.7](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5621)

Says that this is an Magento 2 bug.